# Submit button not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am working on a website and I can't seem to get my submit button to send the message unless I redirect it to the PHP file instead of displaying the message on the original contact page. I'm pretty sure the issue is within my HTML file but I can't seem to figure out how to fix it. Any help is much appreciated!

```js
$(function() {
    $('#contactForm').validate({
        "rules":{
            "contactName":"required",
            "contactEmail":{
                "required":true,
                "email":true
            },
            "contactSubject":"required",
            "contactMessage":"required"
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "sendEmail.php",
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    var getJson = JSON.parse(response);
                    if (getJson.success) {
                        alert('Your message was sent!');
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('There was an error, please try again!');
                    }
                },
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```css
<?php

// Replace this with your own email address
$siteOwnersEmail = '********';


if($_POST) {

   $name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactName']));
   $email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactEmail']));
   $subject = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactSubject']));
   $contact_message = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactMessage']));

   // Check Name
 if (strlen($name) < 2) {
  $fail['name'] = "Please enter your name.";
 }
 // Check Email
 if (!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $fail['email']="Please enter a valid email address.";
    }
 // Check Message
 if (strlen($contact_message) < 15) {
  $fail['message'] = "Please enter your message. It should have at least 15 characters.";
 }
 
   // Subject
 header('Content-type: application/json');
    if (empty($fail)) {
        ini_set("sendmail_from", $siteOwnersEmail); // for windows server
        if ($subject=='')
            $subject="Contact Form Submission";


    $message    =   '';
        $message    .=  "Email from: " . $name . "<br />";
        $message    .=  "Email address: " . $email . "<br />";
        $message    .=  "Message: <br />";
        $message    .=  $contact_message;
        $message    .=  "<br /> ----- <br /> This email was sent from your site's contact form. <br />";
        $from       =   $name . " <" . $email . ">";
        $headers    =   "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
        $headers    .=  "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
        $headers    .=  "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers    .=  "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        # Check if email sent
        if (mail($siteOwnersEmail, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
            # Report true if sent
            $return['success']  =   true;
        }
        else {
            $return['success']  =   false;
            $return['msg']      =   "Something went wrong. Please try again.";
        }
    }
    else {
        $return['success']  =   false;
        # end if - no validation error
        $return['errors']['name']       =   (isset($fail['name'])) ? $fail['name']: false;
        $return['errors']['email']      =   (isset($fail['email'])) ? $fail['email']: false;
        $return['errors']['message']    =   (isset($fail['message'])) ? $fail['message']: false;
    }
    # Display response
    die(json_encode($return));
}

?>
```

```html
<div id="contact-form" class="contact-form">
  <form name="contactForm" id="contactForm" method="post" action="">
    <div class="form-group wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay=".6s">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" class="form-control" name="contactName" id="contactName">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay=".8s">
      <input type="email" placeholder="Your Email" class="form-control" name="contactEmail" id="contactEmail">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="1s">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" class="form-control" name="contactSubject" id="contactSubject">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="1.2s">
      <textarea rows="6" placeholder="Message" class="form-control" name="contactMessage" id="contactMessage"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button class="wow fadeInDown submitform" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="1.4s">Submit</button>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Check first if you have same id for two element

Comment: Use the done and fail callbacks instead of success and fail

Comment: Instead of success and error I mean

Comment: use an <a> instead of submit input or <button>, because they are form elements, they will submit the form defaultly when clicked, but you didn't setup the action of the form。

Comment: Ok, so I changed the callbacks, checked the id's and also tried using <button> but didn't get any changes. It still just refreshes the page.  Maybe there is an issue in my JS?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you have flaws in both your PHP and your JavaScript. First on your PHP, you have a syntax error (too many end braces). I have notated areas where changes are required:

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $siteOwnersEmail='***********';
    $name               =   trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactName']));
    $email              =   trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactEmail']));
    $subject            =   trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactSubject']));
    $contact_message    =   trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactMessage']));
    if (strlen($name) < 2) {
        $fail['name']="Please enter your name.";
    }
    # Use the built-in email address checker
    if (!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $fail['email']="Please enter a valid email address.";
    }
    if (strlen($contact_message) < 15) {
        $fail['message']="Please enter your message. It should have at least 15 characters.";
    }
    # Create header
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    # YOU NEED TO CHECK EMPTY. If you do simply !$fail, you may get an undefined variable warning
    if (empty($fail)) {
        ini_set("sendmail_from", $siteOwnersEmail); // for windows server
        if ($subject=='')
            $subject="Contact Form Submission";
        # You have to first set this or you get a warning
        $message    =   '';
        $message    .=  "Email from: " . $name . "<br />";
        $message    .=  "Email address: " . $email . "<br />";
        $message    .=  "Message: <br />";
        $message    .=  $contact_message;
        $message    .=  "<br /> ----- <br /> This email was sent from your site's contact form. <br />";
        $from       =   $name . " <" . $email . ">";
        $headers    =   "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
        $headers    .=  "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
        $headers    .=  "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers    .=  "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        # Check if email sent
        if (mail($siteOwnersEmail, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
            # Report true if sent
            $return['success']  =   true;
        }
        else {
            $return['success']  =   false;
            $return['msg']      =   "Something went wrong. Please try again.";
        }
    }
    else {
        $return['success']  =   false;
        # end if - no validation error
        $return['errors']['name']       =   (isset($fail['name'])) ? $fail['name']: false;
        $return['errors']['email']      =   (isset($fail['email'])) ? $fail['email']: false;
        $return['errors']['message']    =   (isset($fail['message'])) ? $fail['message']: false;
    }
    # Display response
    die(json_encode($return));
}
```

In your JavaScript, you need a few changes:

```
<script>
// Start with document ready
$(function() {
    $('#contactForm').validate({
        // Create some rules for your form
        "rules":{
            "contactName":"required",
            "contactEmail":{
                "required":true,
                "email":true
            },
            "contactSubject":"required",
            "contactMessage":"required"
        },
        // Submit on validation
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "sendEmail.php",
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                // I generally do success here...
                success: function(response) {
                    // Check that it's returning something
                    console.log(response);
                    // Should return json, so parse it (or change dataType to json)
                    var getJson =   JSON.parse(response);
                    // Message was sent
                    if (getJson.success) {
                        alert('Your message was sent!');
                    }
                    // There was an error
                    else {
                        alert('There was an error, please try again!');
                    }
                },
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Last note, make sure you add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1);` at the top of your PHP pages and fix the warnings you receive.

Comment: This is awesome. I made those changes, but it still results in refreshing only. Do you think it could be due to not having the .submit within the ajax?

Comment: So when you click the submit, it reloads the page is what you are saying?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention that I don't get the return displayed in the console.

Comment: Ok then you have a javascript issue. Are you sure you are adding the jQuery Validate library appropriately? If you are, then you need to check you console to see js errors.

Comment: I only say this because what I have supplied is tested and works, so you will have some other issue with javascript going on if your page is reloading on submit. The jq validate stops the page from reloading, so if you a) aren't including that library, that validate won't work b) have another error that occurs in your js somewhere, it will cancel out the jq validation.

Comment: I have the validate in my library, it must be an error canceling it out. Ultimately, all that is happening is the submit button refreshes the page. It doesn't run any of the check established in the PHP or anything.

Comment: Sorry got busy, do you have a site link or is this a localhost site?

Comment: This is localhost, but I just got it to work! Actually you did, so thank you so much! There are a few errors in the JS and the problem was an extra tag that wasn't meant to be in there. Crazy how something seemingly so small can affect it that much! Anyway, the alert doesn't popup but the message does send now.

Comment: Hmmm, if you have exactly as I have it, it should work perfectly, message and all. Well, at least you have most of it working I guess!

Comment: The error is an unexpected token at json.success and json.parse

Comment: You have to use `console.log(response);` to see what is being responded. It's possible there is an error on the php page that is wrecking the response

Comment: Ok, I did that and the result was "Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined" This is the error specified without the console.log(response): "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)"

Comment: You mustn't have exactly as I have, that would be impossible, can you make an edit with what you have in your js?

Comment: Ok I made the edit, the only thing I changed from the JS you have above was removing the <script> With that in there it wouldn't run.